# how to authenticate project that is deployed on gcp with secret manager in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

i decided to use secret manager in gcp for credentials from some external API's so what i did locally to test stuff was gcloud auth application-default login, before that i downloaded gcp cli locally. While deploying app my application context aren't loading. this is a part from build :
[image]

here is test some basic context load:

```
@SpringBootTest
class FlightApiApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

and here is my docker file :

```
FROM gradle:7.4.1-jdk17-alpine AS TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY build.gradle settings.gradle $APP_HOME

COPY gradle $APP_HOME/gradle
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
USER root
RUN chown -R gradle /home/gradle/src

RUN gradle build || return 0
COPY . .
RUN gradle clean build
FROM openjdk:17
ENV ARTIFACT_NAME=FlightApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/

WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE $APP_HOME/build/libs/$ARTIFACT_NAME .

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT exec java -jar ${ARTIFACT_NAME}
```

i ll put some dependency as well in gradle :

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"

    //amadeus implementation
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.amadeus:amadeus-java:5.9.0"

    implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager:3.3.0'

    implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:25.3.0')

    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage'


    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    //Junit
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'
}
```

Question is should i export in gradle somehow this google default credentials in dockerfile ? Or maybe shall i make some service for authenticating oauth with gcp ? Shouldn't it find automaticaly since im building it in gcp build service. I am open on any ideas, those gcp documentation are quite not understandable for me or just there is too many information about anything. I am using jdk17 this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found example and in my case in gcp build i had a problem with google credentials defaults so in tests that i didn't need secret manager i used this flag :

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.cloud.gcp.secretmanager.enabled=false"})
```

so it worked for me builds goes greeny!
[image]